# How to fix VLC sorting playlist wrongly?

Tags: mac, vlc-media-player, sorting, playlists, smart-playlist

Scenario: VLC 3.08, the playlist have more than 20 tracks and is sorted as follow

```
1. VideoA
2. VideoB
(...)
11.VideoX
12.VideoY
(...)
20.Video Z
(...)
```

Problem: The sorting by title ends up like this

```
1. VideoA
11.VideoX
12.VideoY
(...)
2. VideoB
20.Video Z
(...)
```

How to **sort by title** properly without having to drag and drop every time I play a new playlist?

Comment: VLC just seems to use ASCII sort rather than Natural sort. I'd say it's a no fix. You'll have to compensate by using 2-digit numbers. 01, 02,… etc

Comment: you can select the list of 10, 11, 12 ..etc then drag them to the end of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Folder listing test files

[image: Folder listing test files]

### Media -> Open Folder -> testing

[image: Media -> Open Folder -> testing]

### View upon opening folder, notice it follows Windows file order

[image: View upon opening folder, notice it follows Windows file order]

### Clicking on the title bar causes the problem you see, both when ascending and descending

[image]

### Metadata

[image: Metadata]

### Using the opposite of the file naming scheme above produces much better results when using the title bar, both ascending and descending

[image: example_1]
[image: example_2]

### Solution?

Always start with letters and end with numbers when naming files in the future, your much less likely to run into sorting problems, I do remember you said you have bunch of stuff using the naming scheme already though, so for those just make sure you open the folder in VLC, instead of say for example highlighting the files in file explorer and right clicking add file to VLC, if you do that you'll encounter the sorting problem again. Even better would be to add metadata as well instead of relying on the file names, a number of plugins for VLC can add metadata automatically without you needing to do it by hand ([VLC extensions](https://addons.videolan.org/browse/cat/323/order/latest/)). You can also, if you decide you want to rename those files still, use a batch renamer, it makes the process much faster and easier (perhaps [F2 Utility](https://github.com/Jelmerro/F2Utility), note I don't use a Mac myself, so I got it from this list of suggestions here: [alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/bulk-rename-utility/?platform=mac), apparently the Mac OS already has a basic bulk renamer as well, [CNET](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/two-ways-to-batch-rename-files-on-a-mac/)).

Hope that solves your problem, I know Macs might handle this stuff differently so let me know if this didn't help.

Comment: The default sorting by title is what creates the problem. Instead going from 1 to 2 it goes from 1 to 10 all the way to 19 before going to 2 then goes to 20 and so on. It does not =/

Comment: Huh, you can right click on the playlist and try sort by: title ascending, title descending. What playlist list view mode are you using? Is it detailed list? You could try going into Tools-Preferences and hit reset preferences at the bottom. In Tools-Preferences-Advanced-Main Interfaces-Qt has options that might be relevant but I didn't see any that would fix the problem and you can check playlist options in there as well.

Comment: You might also want to try another file naming style and see if that changes anything, I run a Plex server on my PC and I use the file naming style suggested by the TVDB. For example Horizon s01e01 - name of episode | Horizon s01e02 - name of episode

Comment: The problem persists either ascending or descending, VLC currently thinks 11 is higher than 1 but lower than 2... I guess the default one, never changed or can't see this option on Mac, i can hide or show more info about the video (author, duration, title...) from there. Renaming becomes impractical with multiple playlists which happens often. Guess I'll have to wait for a bug fix.

Comment: I suppose you could try VLC's portable exe, from portableapps.com, and see if you get the same bug there. I'm not getting anything like that on my end and I'm on the latest version as well. Do you have any plugins installed by any chance? https://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable

Comment: @Kyle - .exes don't run on Macs without some considerable faffing around. This is just the way VLC sorts. Unlike both macOS & Windows which use Natural sorting, VLC uses an older sort type, ASCII, which isn't 'smart' when it comes to numbers.

Comment: Yeah I forgot you said Mac, I guess you already know you can use bootcamp, but I hear that can be  bit of a pain of course. I don't think its sorts that way on Windows, but maybe I never noticed the behavior.

Comment: @Kyle - It would take you a whole 5 minutes to test ;)

Comment: Good point, let me run a test on my end see if I get the same behavior in windows, and let you guys know if there is a difference and if there is I'll post a screenshot in the answer

Comment: Alright think I found a solution

Comment: Pretty much as my initial comment. It uses ASCII sorting, not Natural, so you have to fix it in the file names, either strictly alphabetical or use double digits 01, 02, etc.

Comment: Will opening it by folder not give you mac's file order? If not why not use a batch renamer or use an extension to say get the track numbers and sort by that?

Comment: @Kyle Ty, though it's not optimal, the automator alternative looks like a less troublesome workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about the VLC playlist order (be it by name or path) is that it takes the bits values of the individual numbers as references for the order instead of properly converting the number into an actual number (also known as an "integer" or "int" in programs).

VLC doesn't read "numbers" as we do and use the same method to order numbers as it does with letters or other symbols.

So, from VLC view as an app, that 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. is not a number, but a symbol and number symbols seems to have a priority over other symbols, hence the order will place, first, all file with a name/path that starts with 0, them 1. then 2 and so on. If 2 file has the same value, it check the 2nd symbol and order from that up until all file have been compiled in the order.

The order in priority, in bits, is usually numbers, then universal symbols, then letters, then other symbols and letters depending on the system base language.